# Unique Id in JPA (multi tenant)

Tags: jpa, multi-tenant

I'm currently working on a multi tenant applcation which is using JPA (Hibernate). For some tables I need a sequential number thats unique for each tenant. Because of this I cannot use `@GeneratedValue` for these fields. I decided to use an extra entity called Sequence with a `long` field annotated with `@Version`. When requesting a new id I do the following:

```
Sequence seq = em.find(Sequence.class, pk, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
long nextId = seq.id;
```

This works as long as I don't run the application twice. Then I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException:
>   org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by
>   another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Sequence doesn't get locked "properly" and I get an exception as soon as I commit. I can't detect it earlier since JPA doesn't support nested transactions. I tried a few other things but they failed, too.

So, are there any other (portable) solutions that allow me to generate an unique key in a multi tenant context?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the @Version annottion properly. This annotation designs a numeric field as the version field and is used internally by JPA when doing transaction locks. You shouldn't really write or even (except some situations) read it. Your inital idea was right: make a sequencer, but you don't need to use @Version for that. Just have a class with an atomic integer that is incremented each time you need a new unique value, and then persisted to the db in a table.

Comment: I already tried your suggestion. The problem with this solution is that I don't detect transaction overlaps until I commit the whole transaction (that's what I meant by nested transactions).

Comment: Well, you won't like my suggestion, but you may want to ditch Hibernate/JPA if you really want nested transactions. You can go directlly to JDBC, or use Spring SavePoints (with JDBC), to simulat nested transactions: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/transaction/SavepointManager.html